# Table's formats on Google Chrome (pure html)

Tags: html, html-table

I'm trying to understand where I'm making the mistake on this code, but I can't. Works fine on Firefox and IE, but in Chrome the inner cells are not centered like the code seems to do.

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%">
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="7"></td>
        <td style="width: 600px; height: 100px;">&nbsp;</td>
        <td rowspan="7"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="style1" valign="top"><?php echo($title); ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="style2" valign="top"><?php echo($subtitle); ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="style3" valign="top"><?php echo($content); ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="style4"><?php echo($endtitle); ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 600px; height: 30px"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 600px; height: 100px" class="style5" valign="top"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Style1 and 2 and so are simple as:

```
.style1 {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
    font-size: 32px;
    color: #2B2B2B;
    width: 600px;
}
```

With only some fonts diferents

The firts image shows how google chrome renders it, and the second how firefox do it:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't define width for your `td` so it takes the whole width of the parent element. If you add `td {width:600px;}` will be the same for chrome also.
If you inspect the `td` with firebug you will find under DOM that the `offsetWidth` for is `600`, but if you do the same with Developer tools of Chrome, you will see that the `offsetWidth` is `1900` (or any value according to your screen). So to get the same result in all browser you have to set a fixed width as I describe above.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the width to be in your table. Setting the width in your td is improper form. Your html should look like this:

```
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width:600px">
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="7"></td>
        <td style="width: 600px; height: 100px;">&nbsp;</td>
        <td rowspan="7"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="style1" valign="top"><?php echo($title); ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="style2" valign="top"><?php echo($subtitle); ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="style3" valign="top"><?php echo($content); ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="style4"><?php echo($endtitle); ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 600px; height: 30px"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 600px; height: 100px" class="style5" valign="top"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And your styling should look like:

```
.style1 {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
    font-size: 32px;
    color: #2B2B2B;
    width: 100%;
}
```